# Why isn't a set like $\{0,1,3,6,8\}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_9$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why are there only 3 subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_9$? What about $\{0,1,3,6,8\}$? There is an identity and inverse for each element in that subset.

Comment: What operation are you expecting to do here? If addition then where would `1+1` go as `2` isn't in the set? You need to remember that the subgroup has to be closed under that operation.

Comment: It is not closed under the group operation. E.g. $1 + 3 = 4$ is not in the set.

Comment: Got it! Thank you all very much!

Comment: Nice to have a question whose answer is $1+1=2$.

Comment: lol I lost my  mind for 1 sec and posted this question haha. I just learnt the group theory, not very used to it.

Answer (score 4):

A subgroup, besides containing the identity and being closed under taking inverses, must be closed under the group operation.  Your example is not since (for instance) $1\in\{0,1,3,6,8\}$ but $1+1=2\not\in\{0,1,3,6,8\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any trick finding subgroups?

Comment: As mentioned in Soke's answer, Lagrange's theorem can help a lot.  Being closed under the operation is also a very strong condition.  For instance, if you have a subgroup that contains $1$, it must contain $1+1=2$, and then it must also contain $2+1=3$, and so on, so it must actually be the whole group.  So the only subgroup containing $1$ is the whole group.  Playing around with things like this for elements other than $1$ can show you that there aren't very many possibilities for subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a subgroup must also be closed under the group operation $*$. Furthermore, note by Lagrange's theorem we know that if $G$ is finite, then you must have that $|H| \text{ divides } |G|$ if $H$ is a subgroup. Note that  $|\{0, 1, 3, 6, 8\}| = 5$ which does not divide $9$.

A neat trick is a subset $H \subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $a*b^{-1} \in H$ for every $a, b \in H$.